# Django: Creating bound form from model instance

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-forms

I am trying to write my first unit test in Django. It's for a Staff registration form.
The Staff model for the form has a OneToOne relation with a UserProfile (AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE).
The UserProfile has a OneToOne relation with django.contrib.auth.models.User.

I am using https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy to create a test model instance for the staff model. The idea is to use a StaffFactory so I can easily create test model instances. To create a bound form I need to pass it a data dict. I thought it would be convenient to just use **django.forms.models.model_to_dict** to convert my model instance into a data dict when testing the form.

Now, my problem is: model_to_dict does not traverse the foreign keys of my Staff model (Staff->UserProfile->User). This means the form stays invalid since required fields like the User's email are still missing inside the form data.

Currently my StaffRegistrationFormTest looks like:

```
class StaffRegistrationFormTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_success(self):
    staff1 = StaffFactory()

    form = StaffRegistrationForm(model_to_dict(staff1))
    # print jsonpickle.encode(model_to_dict(staff1))
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid(), form.errors)
```

Is there a way to pass in a dict, where the foreign keys are serialized by re-using a model instance?

Comment: upvote for clear sourcing for model_to_dict().  This saved me an hour today.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems as if one way of solving this is by creating additional dictionaries for the OneToOne fields of the Staff model and merging them.

This makes the test pass:

```
    data = dict(model_to_dict(staff1).items() + 
        model_to_dict(staff1.profile).items() +
        model_to_dict(staff1.profile.user).items())
    form = StaffRegistrationForm(data=data)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid(), form.errors)
```

I am not sure if this is the way to go in terms of best practice. Feel free to comment if this it completely against the grain.